# Storing file in chunks(in binary format) and retrieving it using c

Tags: c, file, filesystems, file-handling, distributed-system

I am trying to implement a distributed file system and for that I have to read files in chunks (files can be of any type image, audio, video, text, etc).

```
`typedef struct chunk_structure{
int chunk_id;

int is_last;

char file_name[100];

char buffer[2048];

//some other fields
}`
```

I am reading 2048 bytes from the file using **fread** copy it to a **struct chunk_structure** variable and pass it on to the data server. Data server stores each chunk to a different binary file using **fwrite** but while retrieving the value, though, I get some of the file contents, I also get some random characters.

Can someone please explain what could have gone wrong? or if can anyone suggest a different way of doing this.

Comment: If someone downvotes the question, please state the reason as well so that I can improve next time.

Comment: Can you show how you're using this in a [mcve]? What platform are you on? Are you opening the files in binary mode?

Comment: Since i dont have much code, I can only speculate, and never answer. Are you sure you are null-terminating the buffer though ?